# How to calculate the stress energy tensor of a particle of rest mass m?

Tags: gravity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I was trying to calculate the stress energy tensor of a point particle of rest mass m whose world line is given by $w^\mu(\tau)$ where $\tau$ is proper time. But I am not getting the correct answer. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? I am thinking along the following lines:

Stress energy tensor is defined as $T_{\mu\nu}=\rho\frac{dw^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dw^\nu}{d\tau}$, where $\rho$ is density. For a point particle the expression closest to it is $m\frac{dw^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dw^\nu}{d\tau}$. It is just not divided by volume. To divide it by volume we multiply it with delta function and obtain $m\frac{dw^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dw^\nu}{d\tau}\frac{\delta^4(x-w(\tau))}{\sqrt{-g}}$. However here there is an additional division by time and hence this represents not $T_{\mu\nu}$ but $\frac{\partial T_{\mu\nu}}{\partial t}$. Hence:

$$\frac{\partial T_{\mu\nu}}{\partial t}=m\frac{dw^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dw^\nu}{d\tau}\frac{\delta^4(x-w(\tau))}{\sqrt{-g}}.$$
Integrating and taking rest mass $m$ out of integration sign we obtain the final expression
$$T_{\mu\nu}=m\int \frac{dw^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dw^\nu}{d\tau}\frac{\delta^4(x-w(\tau))}{\sqrt{-g}}dt.$$
Now I think $\sqrt{-g}$ can't be taken out of the integration sign as it may be a function of spacetime. This is however wrong. **The correct answer is:**

**$$
T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{m}{\sqrt{-g}}\int \frac{dw^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dw^\nu}{d\tau}\delta^4(x-w(\tau))d\tau.$$**

**My questions:**
*Why $d\tau$ is the correct variable of integration and not $dt$ ?*
*Why $\sqrt{-g}$ has been taken out of the integral as if it is a constant* ?

Comment: The equation $\frac{dT_{\mu\nu}}{dt} = m \frac{d\omega_\mu}{d\tau}  \frac{d\omega_\nu}{d\tau} \frac{\delta^{(4)}(x-\omega(\tau))}{\sqrt{-g}}$ doesn't look correct. The left hand side is not a 2-tensor while the right hand side is.

Comment: Actually, if you remedy the left hand side my differentiating w.r.t $d\tau$ instead of $dt$, then your second question is automatically answered. If the integration variable is $d\tau$, the affine parameter, then the metric doesn't depend on it (it depends on x of the delta function) and you can pull it out of the integral. I am not writing this as an answer because I still can't explain clearly why the derivative should be w.r.t. $d\tau$ in the first place, although it is clear to me intuitively that it should be true.

Comment: Your comments are useful. Thanks.